# C language array byte size

Tags: c

```
char *myArray[] = { "aaaaaa", "ccccc", "bbbbbb", "111111" };

printf("%d\n", sizeof(myArray));

printf("%d\n", (int)(&myArray + 1) - (int)(&myArray));
```

My question is about why passing myArray into `sizeof` can get the same result as the second method.

I know `myArray` represent a address which points to the first of four int space addresses, but how does `sizeof` recognize the size of bytes of 4 `int` space?

`sizeof` is not a function, what is it?

Comment: [sizeOf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is a unary operator.

Comment: "*I know myArray represent a address which points to the first...*" Not when passed to `sizeof`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", sizeof(myArray));` --> `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(myArray));`

Comment: `myArray` is an *array* of `char*`. In many cases, it *decays* into a pointer to `char*`. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: See this doc for [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why passing myArray into sizeof can get the same result as the second method.

```
char *myArray[] = { "aaaaaa", "ccccc", "bbbbbb", "111111" };
```

`myArray` is array of 4 pointers to `char`. So `sizeof(myArray) = 4*sizeof(pointer_to_char)`. Typically in 64 bit machine `sizeof(pointer)` is 64 bit (8 bytes), and so it's 32 bytes.

As for your second printf

```
printf("%d\n", (int)(&myArray + 1) - (int)(&myArray));
```

Because `myArray` is array, then `&myArray` is pointer to array. Here `(&myArray + 1)` points to the next array of pointers. Think of that as the next block of 4 pointers to char. And so `(&myArray + 1) - (&myArray)` is the same as the size of the original array of pointers.

---

Btw, you should use proper `printf` control string:

- For `sizeof`, use `%zu`:

  printf("%zu\n", sizeof(myArray));
- Your 2nd printf works but would give an warning with regard the cast to int:

  `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]`

That warning can be get rid of by:

```
char *p_start = (char *)(&myArray + 1);
char *p_end = (char *)(&myArray);
printf("%td", p_start - p_end );
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(myArray)` gives you the size of an array of 4 character pointers, probably 4x4=16. `sizeof` is an operator, which is in most cases evaluated at compile-time. It is defined by the language to do this task - the language says that `sizeof`'s job is to know the size of things, so that's how it knows.

`&myArray` gives you an array pointer of type `char (*)[4]`. `&myArray+1` does arithmetic on such an array, giving the address of an array pointer pointing just past the 4x4 array. If you subtract that address with the original address, you will get the size of the array in bytes.

There is no real difference between the two forms functionality-wise, except `sizeof` is so much more readable.

---

(As a side note, the second version results in a type called `ptrdiff_t`, and if you wish to print this with printf, you should use the %tu format specifier.)